# DRF annotate Count on many-to-many through table gives more occurrences than when you use _set.all().count()

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have these models:

```
class Topic(BaseModel):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    public_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)

class Content(BaseModel):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    series = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    season = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    episode = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(tags_models.Tag, through='ContentHasTags')
    topics = models.ManyToManyField(topics_models.Topic, through='ContentHasTopics')

class ContentHasTopics(BaseModel):

    content = models.ForeignKey(Content)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(topics_models.Topic)

    order = models.IntegerField(default=99)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('content', 'topic',)
        ordering = ('order',)
```

The problem I have is that if I use the next function:

```
@property
def get_contents_count(self):
    return self.contenthastopics_set.all().count()
```

In many cases I have 7 as a result (and is true), but when I use the annotate query like this for Django Rest Framework (in the viewset), it gives me like 28 results, some other topics have 5 contents using the _set.all().count(), but annotate gives me 10 as a result, and so on.

```
queryset = models.Topic.objects.all().annotate(
    themes_count=Count('themehastopics')
).annotate(
    contents_count=Count('contenthastopics')
).annotate(
    tags_count=Count('topichastags')
)
```

How is the right way to annotate the query with the Count correctly added?

Comment: Using distinct would resolve the issue, using annotation over a related table with one/many to many relation duplicates the result due to table join.
If you use postgreSQL you could even pass an argument to distinct().

Comment: Thanks Azee, I was looking more and found that I can use the distinct() function inside the Count, so using Count('contenthastopics', distinct=True), works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is finally how I solved this problem:

```
queryset = models.Topic.objects.all().annotate(
    themes_count=Count('themehastopics', distinct=True),
    contents_count=Count('contenthastopics', distinct=True),
    tags_count=Count('topichastags', distinct=True)
)
```